# convert a string range of values to numeric range

Tags: r

I have the following type of values in one column of data.

```
£48.00 - £52.00
```

First I have to remove the £ sign, done with

```
v <- gsub('£'," ",£48.00 - £52.00)
```

`v` is now a string.

```
> v
[1] " 48.00 -  52.00"
```

How can we transform `v` to numeric so `v` is `48.00 - 52.00`?

Comment: Do you want this to be a subtraction or a range?

Comment: I want this to be a range

Comment: In that case, the strsplit should work

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a range" and "numeric". akrun's comment gives the numeric range (at one pound increments); and if you just want the boundaries, stop at his `x1`... like `lapply(strsplit(str1,"[ £-]+"),function(x)as.numeric(x[-1]))`

Comment: R doesn't have a simple data type for a "range." What do you mean when you say that?

Comment: " 48.00 - 52.00" is converted to 48.00 - 52.00 so I can compute the midpoint

Comment: @akrun. It gives lapply(strsplit(a, '[£-]'), function(x) {x1 <- na.omit(as.numeric(x));x1[1]:x1[2]})
[[1]]
[1] 48 49 50 51 52

Comment: @akrun, I don't need it. I used the following. lapply(strsplit(a, '[£-]'), function(x) {x1 <- na.omit(as.numeric(x));(x1[1]+x1[2])/2}). It gives the midpoint 50. However some of the values are just £40.00 and gives NA since there is no x1[2]

Comment: Assuming that you need `median`,  `lapply(strsplit(str1, '[£-]'), function(x) {median(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE)})`

Comment: @akrun. Thanks. It is working but I have got 50 warnings. data$newv<-sapply(strsplit(data$v, '[£-]'), 
                        function(x) {median(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE)})
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50). 50: In median(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I think the warning must when `''` are converted to NAs by coercing to numeric with `as.numeric` (if I am not wrong) which is a friendly one.

Comment: @ akrun. Excellent akrun! How can I show my thumbs up to you in this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_extract` to extract only the numeric part along with the `.`.  The output will be a `list`.  We can loop through the list with `sapply` and get the `median` after converting to 'numeric'.

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(str1, '[0-9.]+'), function(x) median(as.numeric(x)))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "£48.00 - £52.00"
```